# Are (specific) diff/patch tools suitable to update an executable binary file?

Tags: diff, updates, binaryfiles, patch

I've just read [this paper](http://www.daemonology.net/papers/bsdiff.pdf) which presents the **BSDiff** tool as a method to diff-and-patch binary files. I wonder whether these types of tools are good and suitable in systems which can't afford any kind of error in this process.

I'm working in an embedded project and we are looking for ways to update the bootloader image without transferring the whole new version, but only small pieces. The binary image that we want to update, encompasses not only the application we've developed but also the OS (FreeRTOS) and third party libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Try this implementation of BSDiff: 
https://github.com/Cheedoong/bsdiff
Cross-platform, and with no dependency on other library.